# Count the nodes with most connection in a network in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to count the number nodes with more received connections in a unidirectional network.

For example in a network like this:

```
g <- graph( c('A',1,'A',2,'A',3,'B',4,'B',5,'B',6,'C',7,'C',8,'D',7,'D',8))
```

We would have 3 independent components

Loading the data in a file (test), I can upload it and represent it as follows:

```
plot(g)
```

[image: plot graph]

How can I get the destination nodes with more connections? In this case will be node 7 and 8.

Following another question ([r igraph most connected nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799702/r-igraph-most-connected-nodes)) I tried the following:

```
lengths(as_adj_list(g))

A 1 2 3 B 4 5 6 C 7 8 D 
3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

The result is counting the lengths of all the nodes, but I'm looking at the destination nodes only.

I tried also:

```
 sort(g, decreasing = TRUE)

 Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : index larger than maximal 12
```

As you see I get an error message

Following on commentary: With the following I get the count of the destination nodes, but how do I get the ones with the maximum count?

```
degree(g4, mode = "in")
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could improve your question. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve it accordingly. A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session. To your question: `igraph::degree(g, mode = "in")` might help.

Comment: Thanks lukeA. I've edited the code to simplify. Thanks also for your code suggestion. I don' see thought how to get the ones with the most connections though :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph( c('A',1,'A',2,'A',3,'B',4,'B',5,'B',6,'C',7,'C',8,'D',7,'D',8))
V(g)$indeg <- degree(g, mode = "in")
V(g)[V(g)$indeg == max(V(g)$indeg)]
#  2/12 vertices, named:
# [1] 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks lukeA, that is fantastic!! Thank you.